# Selecting polygon feature classes with one record in Oracle geodatabase using SQL query?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql, query

I have an Oracle Enterprise geodatabase with many feature classes. I would like a SQL query to find all the polygon feature classes with only one record in its table. So far, I can only query all the feature classes.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM SDE.GDB_ITEMS items INNER JOIN SDE.GDB_ITEMTYPES itemtypes ON items.Type = itemtypes.UUID
  WHERE itemtypes.Name = 'Feature Class'
```

Answer (score 0):

Several parts are involved:

- getting all the tables from the database (used code from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9954833/3346915)
- reading geodatabase metadata (in your question body)
- filtering using the `where` clause to include only those tables that are of `feature class` type and their shape type are of `polygon` ([parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344553/how-can-i-query-a-value-in-sql-server-xml-column) is involved).

This code would work on SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.NAME,
    TableSchema = s.Name,
    RowCounts = p.rows
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID 
    AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
    t.name in (
        (SELECT PARSENAME(items.Name,1)
          FROM SDE.GDB_ITEMS items INNER JOIN SDE.GDB_ITEMTYPES itemtypes 
          ON items.Type = itemtypes.UUID
          WHERE itemtypes.Name = 'Feature Class' and 
                Definition.value('(/DEFeatureClassInfo/ShapeType)[1]', 
                'varchar(max)') = 'esriGeometryPolygon'))   
    and t.is_ms_shipped = 0 
    and p.rows = 1

GROUP BY
    t.NAME, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    s.Name, t.Name
```

The results:

```
    TableName           TableSchema      RowCounts
--  ------------------  -------------  -----------
 0  ND_1226_DIRTYAREAS  dbo                      1
 1  REDLINING           dbo                      1
 2  SS_WORKAREAS        dbo                      1
 3  T_1_DIRTYAREAS      dbo                      1
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that i am using oracle. Sry about it

Comment: I don't have access to any Oracle instance right now. The geodatabase metadata tables should contain the same things. The only different pieces would be `parsename` - `regexp_substr()` and how you parse the XML in Oracle - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982687/oracle-plsql-how-to-parse-xml-and-insert-into-table

Comment: Ah, that's right, the info about system tables is stored differently... This would be slightly more challenging, but you should start somewhere here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle or post a question on SO or DBA.SE